# How can I remove a flag, if the user edited and improved later?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

I see low quality post. So I flagged it as "it is very low quality". After a few minutes the user improved his post. Now I want to remove my flag to that post. I searched, but there is no option like "remove flag" or "unflag" or anything else.

On my flag summary page in my profile, the flag is shown to be active. I don't want to see that question in my flags list, because it no longer belongs there.

How can I remove my flag to that question?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can't cancel a flag once it has been cast. Don't worry about it though, it will be dismissed at some point.

A proposal to make cancelling flags possible [has already been made](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Update:  Flags can now be self-retracted:  Refer to: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags/281010#281010

Comment: ... retracted before approved it is. Very useful.

Comment: Wish the whole flagging process, including the ability to self-retract, was better defined in the help sections, and more prominently displayed within the profile.  While I rarely want to see what I've flagged, those times that I do, I find myself hunting all over my profile for it.