# Remove a casted flag

Tags: support, flags

I have flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424800/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-the-minimum-or-maximum-value-from-an-array-of-number/52973393#52973393) as not an answer, but now that I look at it again it is a proper answer. When I saw it, it was like this:

```
public void findMaxValue(){
   int[] my_array = {1,2,,6,5,8,3,9,0,23};
}
```

But the user has modified it since then. How can I remove my flag?

Comment: Related: [How can I remove a flag, if the user edited and improved later?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251661/7795130), however that was answered back when we didn't have the option to retract flags, which was added in August of 2016: [Cancel misclicked flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/363946). Maybe we should mark the 2014 question as a dupe of this one so that if someone is searching, they can find this question that has a correct answer? Or alternatively add an answer with the updated information to the past question, and mark this one as a duplicate of the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the "flag" button again, and the button at the bottom will be "retract flag".

Note that the flag was never valid in the first place: see [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/335772)